# Get Text Area Value inside Grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Inside of a GridView's TemplateField i have a HTML-TextArea:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Message">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <textarea id="txtArStatusMsg" cols="20" rows="2" style="width: 99%"></textarea>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Q: how can i read the text of the text-area in the SelectedRow of the GridView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `runat="server"` to the textarea and call `FindControl("txtArStatusMsg")` on the [SelectedRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrow.aspx) of the GridView.
To get the `TextAreas`'s text, you need to cast it to a [HtmlTextArea](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltextarea.aspx) and read it's [Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltextarea.value.aspx) property.

```
var text = ((HtmlTextArea)GridView1.SelectedRow.FindControl("txtArStatusMsg")).Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use/access html `<input/>` tag at server-side until you are not  adding `runat="server"` attribute. It is better to use TextBox and set TextMode=Multiline.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Message">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <textarea 
                id="txtArStatusMsg" 
                cols="20" rows="2" 
                runat="server"
                style="width: 99%">
      </textarea>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

OR

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Message">
       <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:TextBox id="txt1" runat="server" TextMode="Multiline"/>
           <asp:Button id="btn1" runat="server" CommandName="select"/>
       </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Write following code in GridView's `SelectedIndexChanged` handler,

```
//Cells[0] - 0 indicates the 1st cell of selected row.
TextBox tx=GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].FindControl("txt1") as TextBox;
```

Comment: I'll try this TextMode="Multiline" also but right now I have to use textarea only...thnx..